# When is Django REST Framework CURSOR pagination expired?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When using CURSOR pagination in `Django REST Framework`, It uses `cursor` query parameter like `?cursor=xxxxxxx`(Maybe it is a database cursor ID?) and I assume that the cursor will be expired after a while so that it comes to be not available anymore.

Is my assumption is right? if so, when is it expired?

Comment: It doesn't expires. 

By design, cursor pagination follows a never changing ordering scheme, using a unique field, like slug, or datetime stamp.

Comment: Nothing mentioned about that in the doc: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursor pagination doesn't use some external cursor. It just uses one of the fields from the model which is paginating through. This field has to be unique and the source queryset for your view has to always be ordered using this field.

Let's see it on example:

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, unique=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class BlogPostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'created']
```

views.py

```
class BlogPostCursorPagination(CursorPagination):
    page_size = 5
    ordering = '-created'

class BlogPostListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = BlogPostListSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPostCursorPagination
```

Results:

```
GET /posts/
{
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/?cursor=cD0yMDE5LTA1LTEzKzE1JTNBNTYlM0EzNy4xMjI4NjUlMkIwMCUzQTAw",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "Latest post",
            "description": "This is the latest post",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:57:08.574475Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Previous post",
            "description": "This post was created before the latest one",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:57:00.971509Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "2nd previoust post",
            "description": "This one was created even before",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:53.053740Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "3rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:43.804315Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "4rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:37.122865Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, there is some "garbage" set as a cursor in next link. This isn't just garbage, this is a base64-encoded value of `created` field of the last item on the current page. That's it...

If you click on that link, django-rest-framework will decode that and display for you 5 elements AFTER this one, not including itself. It is as simple as:

```
BlogPost.objects.filter(created__lt=datetime(2019, 5, 13, 15, 56, 37, 122865, tzinfo=utc))
```

Note that we are using `__lt`, because the order of items is reversed: the newest records are first.

So if you modify that cursor and replace DateTime inside to the DateTime of 2nd post from list, you will get posts from 3 to 7:

```
GET /posts/?cursor=cD0yMDE5LTA1LTEzKzE1JTNBNTclM0EwMC45NzE1MDklMkIwMCUzQTAw
{
    "next": null,
    "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/?cursor=cj0xJnA9MjAxOS0wNS0xMysxNSUzQTU2JTNBNTMuMDUzNzQwJTJCMDAlM0EwMA%3D%3D",
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "2nd previoust post",
            "description": "This one was created even before",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:53.053740Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "3rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:43.804315Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "4rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:37.122865Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "5rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:29.501963Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "6rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:22.033332Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, there is no validation if the object, that cursor is pointing to, exists in database. If you try to set timestamp slightly after 2nd post, you will get posts from 2 to 6:

```
GET /posts/?cursor=cD0yMDE5LTA1LTEzKzE1JTNBNTclM0EwMC45NzE1MTAlMkIwMCUzQTAw
{
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/?cursor=cD0yMDE5LTA1LTEzKzE1JTNBNTYlM0EyOS41MDE5NjMlMkIwMCUzQTAw",
    "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/?cursor=cj0xJnA9MjAxOS0wNS0xMysxNSUzQTU3JTNBMDAuOTcxNTA5JTJCMDAlM0EwMA%3D%3D",
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "Previous post",
            "description": "This post was created before the latest one",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:57:00.971509Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "2nd previoust post",
            "description": "This one was created even before",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:53.053740Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "3rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:43.804315Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "4rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:37.122865Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "5rd previous post",
            "description": "And so on...",
            "created": "2019-05-13T15:56:29.501963Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. One more question, in your example, should `created` be indexed for performance? and I think `created` couldn't be unique though it is a small chance if two items are created at the same time.

Comment: Yes, `created` can be indexed for performance. No, `created` SHOULD be a unique field, because when it will happen that two dates overlap, there is a possibility that you will never see one of those records (it can be "stuck" between pages if first of them will end up as the last item on a page). If it will happen when unique is there, you can just hit save again. If you really don't wan this, ordering may be also a tuple of multiple fields and it is sufficient that any subset from it is unique. You can use for example `('-created', 'id')` and it will work fine.